# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ;

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

What is wrong with my PLSQL?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REGISTRO_CLIENTE_TARJETA(
v_nombre IN VARCHAR2, 
v_ap_paterno IN VARCHAR2, 
v_ap_paterno IN VARCHAR2, 
v_rfc IN VARCHAR2, 
v_email IN VARCHAR2, 
v_direccion IN VARCHAR2, 
v_numero IN VARCHAR2, 
v_num_seg IN VARCHAR2, 
v_mes_exp IN VARCHAR2, 
v_anio_expiracion IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO TARJETA_DE_CREDITO(TARJETA_ID, NUMERO, NUM_SEGURIDAD, MES_EXPIRACION, ANIO_EXPIRACION) 
VALUES(TARJETA_CREDITO_SEQ.NEXTVAL, v_numero, v_num_seg, v_mes_exp, v_anio_expiracion)

INSERT INTO CLIENTE(CLIENTE_ID,NOMBRE, AP_PATERNO, AP_MATERNO, RFC, EMAIL, DIRECCION, TARJETA_ID)
VALUES(CLIENTE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, v_nombre, v_ap_paterno, v_ap_paterno, v_rfc, v_email, v_direccion, (SELECT LAST_NUMBER FROM ALL_SEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = 'TERCERO_SEQ'))

END;
```

I'm getting the following errors using the show errors command:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
14/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
15/88    PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
19/3     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
         one of the following:
         := . ( @ % ;
```

Comment: You need semicolon at the end of each VALUES(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSERT` statements must end with a `semi-colon`.

`insert into table (columns list) values (values list);`

As a good practice, always compile your code in `SQL*Plus`  and do `SHOW ERROR`. Look at the `line number` in the `error stack`. Without any `EXCEPTION` block (or with proper exception handling), you would get the correct line number. Try to `debug` your code by going to the line number and verify.

Comment: Thanks, that did that part. There was also a repeated record name on ap_paterno.